# Building query in Postgres 9.4.2 for JSONB datatype using builtin function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table schema as follows:

```
DummyTable
-------------
someData JSONB
```

All my values will be a JSON object. For example, when you do a `select * 
from DummyTable`, it would look like

```
someData(JSONB)
------------------
{"values":["P1","P2","P3"],"key":"ProductOne"}
{"values":["P3"],"key":"ProductTwo"}
```

I want a query which will give me result set as follows:

```
[
  {
    "values": ["P1","P2","P3"],
    "key": "ProductOne"
  },
  {
    "values": ["P4"],
   "key": "ProductTwo"
  }
]
```

I'm using Postgres version 9.4.2. I looked at documentation page of the same, but could not find the query which would give the above result.

However, in my API, I can build the JSON by iterating over rows, but I would prefer query doing the same. I tried `json_build_array`, `row_to_json` on a result which would be given by `select * from table_name`, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) is the link I looked for to write a  query for JSONB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_agg or jsonb_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
create table dummytable(somedata jsonb not null);
insert into dummytable(somedata) values
  ('{"values":["P1","P2","P3"],"key":"ProductOne"}'),
  ('{"values":["P3"],"key":"ProductTwo"}');
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(somedata)) from dummytable;
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ProductOne",
        "values": [
            "P1",
            "P2",
            "P3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "ProductTwo",
        "values": [
            "P3"
        ]
    }
]
```

Although retrieving the data row by row and building on client side can be made more efficient, as the server can start to send data much sooner - after it retrieves first matching row from storage. If it needs to build the json array first, it would need to retrieve all the rows and merge them before being able to start sending data.